# OrientDB ETL import: 'skip' operator throws exception

Tags: java, graph, etl, orientdb

I'm trying to import a .csv file into OrientDB v.2.0.13 with the help of the included ETL scripts.

Now to my problem. Using the operator

```
{ "skip": { "expression": "name = '(unassigned)'"} }
```

within my .json config file throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:278)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:186)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:161)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transformer 'skip' not found
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLComponentFactory.getTransformer(OETLComponentFactory.java:141)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:260)
        ... 2 more
```

Without the 'skip' operator my import works flawlessly, so I guess the problem isn't the config file.

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the documentation not updated, please use the [FLOW transformer](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Transformer.html#flow). Example:

```
{ "flow": { "if": "name is null", "operation" : "skip" } }
```